# HERE maps can't use android premium sdk

Tags: android, here-api

I have originally created a project that uses ANDROID SDK STARTER, but now my requirements have changed, so I want to use ANDROID SDK PREMIUM. Since it is the same project, I used the same package name. I downloaded Premium SDK and replaced with old Started SDK, however,  the screen where the map should be is black.

After reverting back to the STARTER sdk, I am able to use it but can't use the Premium sdk.

Is this because the packages are similar in the dev console? If yes, how do I delete the ANDROID SDK STARTER project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I just had to add the code in manifest, particularly

```
1. <meta-data
        android:name="com.here.android.maps.license.key"
        android:value="{YOUR_LICENSE_KEY}" />
2. <meta-data android:name="INTENT_NAME" android:value="YOUR_INTENT_NAME" />
3. <service
            android:name="com.here.android.mpa.service.MapService"
            android:label="YOUR_LABEL_NAME"
            android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="YOUR_INTENT_NAME"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

This was not needed in Started SDK, but needed for Premium